# SQLite failure on attempting to update table

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I'm completely stucked with updating QSLite table.
Here's my code:

```
QSqlQuery tSqlQuery("SELECT load_extension(\'libspatialite-4.dll\')", *sdb);
QSqlQuery addColumnLat;
addColumnLat.prepare("ALTER TABLE roads_nodes ADD COLUMN lat REAL");
QSqlQuery addColumnLon;
addColumnLon.prepare("ALTER TABLE roads_nodes ADD COLUMN lon REAL");
QSqlQuery updateLatLon;
updateLatLon.prepare("UPDATE roads_nodes SET lat=ST_Y(roads_nodes.geometry), lon=ST_X(roads_nodes.geometry)");
    if(addColumnLat.exec())
      if(addColumnLon.exec())
        if(!updateLatLon.exec())
        {
            qDebug() << updateLatLon.lastQuery();
            qDebug() << updateLatLon.lastError().databaseText();
            qDebug() << updateLatLon.lastError().driverText();
        }
    else
       qDebug() << addColumnLat.lastError().text();
```

And here's output:

```
"UPDATE roads_nodes SET lat=ST_Y(roads_nodes.geometry), lon=ST_X(roads_nodes.geometry)"
"No query" 
"Unable to fetch row"
```

Extension loads correctly and actually I can exec SELECT statements with ST_X(geometry_column) and ST_Y(geometry_column)

Previous two ALTER statements exec correctly and new columns are created.

WIDW ?

Comment: why do you not check return result of last prepare statement? It looks like it fails.

Comment: This code does not execute `tSqlQuery`. And what about `sdb`?

Comment: @CL.sdb has valid value and points to db correctly, connection is stablished

Comment: @N1ghtLight ok, I've checked result of preparing query and it is set to false. I've tried to changed code little bit: `QSqlQuery updateLatLon(*sdb);`  but the return result of prepare() still false